# C++ Win32 API Combo Box freezes when opened

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

I'm trying to get a drop-down combo box (`CBS_DROPDOWN` or `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`) to work. The problem is, anytime I open the combo box, the entire window "freezes" (it doesn't respond to anything, can't even close it, it ignores clicks). The only way to "unfreeze" it is to press the "esc" key.

While the window is "frozen" the combo box doesn't receive any messages, no mouse move, clicks etc.

This is the code I'm using to create the combo box:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    hComboBox = CreateWindow("COMBOBOX", nullptr,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
        25, 25, 150, 280, hwnd, (HMENU)12345, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
    populate_cb();
    break;
```

The "populate_cb()" function simply adds some strings to the combo box and sets an initial element:

```
void populate_cb() {
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 1");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 2");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 3");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 4");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 5");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)2, 0);
}
```

However, the simple (`CBS_SIMPLE`) combo boxes work though.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

HWND hComboBox;

void populate_cb() {
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 1");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 2");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 3");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 4");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Item 5");
    SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)2, 0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hComboBox = CreateWindow("COMBOBOX", nullptr,
            WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
            25, 25, 150, 280, hwnd, (HMENU)12345, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
        populate_cb();
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wcex.style = 0;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        MessageBox(nullptr, "Window class registration failed!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "WindowClass", "Window Title",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480, nullptr,
        nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hwnd) {
        MessageBox(nullptr, "Window creation failed!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: You're not responding to one of the combo box notifications by going into an infinite loop, are you?

Comment: I'm not responding to any combo box notifications at all.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. And while not a bug in itself, bitwise OR-ing the `WS_OVERLAPPED` window style indicates, that you decided against reading the documentation.

Comment: need look under debugger - are thread wait to something or spin in infinite loop. callstack. all other windows also freeze ? message loop code not executed more ?

Comment: Here is the complete code: http://pastebin.com/EbPxfyja

Comment: @RbMm I'm sure that debugging won't be needed. A simple MCVE will suffice.

Comment: @vlad not in an offsite link. Here in the question.

Comment: I'm going to guess you have passed the handle of your main window for the second argument of `GetMessage()`. You should usually pass `nullptr` except in certain circumstances.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - may be and not need. however very frequently debugging the most effective way resolve problem and found bug

Comment: @RbMm Few people can debug in the Windows code. I know I've never had to. I know you can do it. But it's not the right way for the rest of us.

Comment: @IInspectable  But most probably he did: see Step 1 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-simple-combo-box

Comment: I have the exact same problem so I am happy I am not alone. The app didn't freeze. It's just not responding to mouse input, but if you use arrow keys that will work. It also prevents mouse input from reaching the parent window as though the listbox was a modal dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0)
```

pumps messages for the main window only. You need to service queued messages for all windows in the thread. Change this line to

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
```

As explained in the documentation for `GetMessage` passing `NULL` for the second argument retrieves messages for all windows owned by the thread.

Comment: Can you please fix the question so that it contains the code.

Comment: Also see [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493).

Comment: I already confirmed I face the same problem as the person that asked the question. Now I can confirm that this answer is dead center on point. Should be the accepted answer. I just want to say, I give up trying to master win32. I will never graduate.